# How do I query an organizational unit for its groups with LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, domaincontroller

I have tried many queries, but this gets me my OU:

`(&(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(Name=MyOU))` (I just get the ou here)

I tried to use `(&(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=group)(Name=MyOU))` but failed.

Also, `(&(objectCategory=Group)(cn=MyOU,dc=mytop,dc=mysuffix))` and failed.

I am trying to get the groups within the OU.  I have searched a lot but cannot come up with it.  How do I find the groups within the OU?  I have a routine that will print out the groups.  I just can't get the query right.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cn=MyOU,dc=mytop,dc=mysuffix` does not go in the filter - this is the Base DN of your search.

The filter you need is just `(objectClass=group)`.

Comment: I actually found this just before I came back here.  I changed my initial search base in my php string from dc=mydomain,dc=domainsuffix, to ou=myou,dc=mydomain,dc=domainsuffix.  Walking away and coming back does wonders sometimes.  Thanks again (to all answerers)/

Comment: I have the same issue but cannot change the base DN. It must be in the query.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying a searchbase instead of adding it to the query. From ldapsearch, you'd do this:

-s dc=MyOU,dc=com *your searchbase may vary*

From vb, you'd specify it in the object:

DirectoryEntry("LDAP://*server IP*//DC=MyOU,DC=com"...

From there, the filter (objectclass=group) should get you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If your using powershell, just use the `-SearchBase` parameter